# Как сделать адаптивное окно в PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qlayout, qmainwindow

Я делаю приложение-викторину на *PyQt5*. Я добавил текст, кнопку и фоновое изображение, но дальше встал вопрос как сделать окно адаптивным?

Я много гуглил, как в рунете так и в англоязычном интернете и ютюбе, но ничего не нашел.

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import sys


class QuizApplication(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QuizApplication, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Quiz")
        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 648, 500)

        self.pixmap = QPixmap("background_image.jpg")
        self.background_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.background_label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.background_label.adjustSize()

        self.welcome_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.welcome_label.move(100, 0)
        self.welcome_label.setText("Это будет викторина по истории, философии и обществознанию")
        self.welcome_label.adjustSize()

        self.start_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.start_button.move(220, 20)
        self.start_button.setText("Нажмите чтобы начать!")
        self.start_button.adjustSize()

def aplication_setup():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QuizApplication()

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    aplication_setup()
```

[image: Это то что у меня получилось]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вам надо изучить [**Qt Main Window Framework**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework)
>
> Примечание. Создание главного окна без центрального виджета не поддерживается. У вас должен быть центральный виджет, даже если это просто заполнитель.
> ...

---

> Научитесь использовать менеджеры компоновки:
> [**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)
> ...

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, \
    QPushButton, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class QuizApplication(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QuizApplication, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Quiz")
# ?        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 648, 500)

        self.centralwidget = QWidget()                               # !!! +++
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")            # !!! +++
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)                    # !!! +++

        self.pixmap = QPixmap("head3.png")
        self.background_label = QLabel(self)
        self.background_label.setObjectName("background_label")      # +++
        self.background_label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
#         self.background_label.adjustSize()

        self.welcome_label = QLabel(self)
        self.welcome_label.setObjectName("welcome_label")            # +++
        self.welcome_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)              # +++
        self.welcome_label.setWordWrap(True)                         # +++
#        self.welcome_label.move(100, 0)
        self.welcome_label.setText(
            "Это будет викторина по истории, философии и обществознанию.")
#         self.welcome_label.adjustSize()
        
        self.start_button = QPushButton(self)
        self.start_button.setObjectName("start_button")              # +++      
#        self.start_button.move(220, 20)
        self.start_button.setText("Нажмите чтобы начать!")
#         self.start_button.adjustSize()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.welcome_label, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.start_button, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignTop)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.background_label, 1, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)


StyleSheet = """
#centralwidget {
    border-image: url(background.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
}
#welcome_label {
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #f77;
}
#start_button {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ADFF2F;
    background-color: #008000; 
}
"""
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)                                      # +++ 
    window = QuizApplication()
    window.resize(648, 500)                                            # +
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**background.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, а что делают методы setObjectName, зачем нужен setCentralWidget и centralwidget, и зачем еще нужен setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter) и setWordWrap(True). А так огромное спасибо !

Comment: @Али-МухаммадЗакарьяев пожалуйста.   Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour Если у вас есть другие проблем - задайте новый вопрос. Я же вам предоставил некоторые ссылки https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework и https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html вы их прочитали? Дополнительно, то что вы спрашиваете можно прочитать https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop и https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#wordWrap-prop

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня репутация меньше 15, а так спасибо, вы мне очень помогли

Comment: @Али-МухаммадЗакарьяев чтобы отметить ответ как правильный, вам не нужна репутация. Прочитайте внимательно, то что я вам писал.

Comment: Здравствуйте еще раз! у меня не работает ваш код. Вместо увеличения и уменьшения виджетов они просто перемещаются в центр, а надпись и кнопка вообще находятся сверху изображения, а не на нем, что делать

Comment: @Али-МухаммадЗакарьяев я ответил на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Извините, но нет. Ваш способ не работает

Comment: @Али-МухаммадЗакарьяев я не понимаю что и как у вас не работает, но я вижу что в вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1535574 вы практический используете код. который предложи вам я. Почему так получается ?

Comment: Я использую QGridLayout , а не QVBoxLayout. И если вы следите за моими вопросами, почему бы вам на них не не ответить? Потому что сейчас для меня мой новый вопрос, на который вы дали ссылку, очень важен. А так я вас очень благодарю, потому что я и вправду использую очень похожий на ваш код

Comment: @Али-МухаммадЗакарьяев какой менеджер компоновки использовать, не играет никакой роли. Да, я просматриваю ВСЕ вопросы. Я не смогу вам помочь пока вы не примите правильное решение на мой ответ на ваш вопрос:  "Как сделать адаптивное окно в PyQt5"

Comment: Извините, но что означает не сможете помочь. Вы же сами сказали, что без разницы, какой менеджер компоновки использовать. И посмотрев на вашу репутацию, я считаю, что для вас мой новый вопрос не должен быть сложным

Comment: Хорошо, допустим я сделаю так как вы сказали, но что дальше, какой ответ на мой новый вопрос?

Comment: Извините пожалуйста. сейчас я снова попробовал ваш код и все заработало!! оказывается просто я не правильно настроил centralwidget. реально спасибо

Comment: @Али-МухаммадЗакарьяев пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: все. пометил. вы имеете ввиду эту галочку возле вопроса?